# Al intentar descargar un archivo en página ASP.NET, aparece el error 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: asp.net, iis

Al momento de descargar un archivo word en mi página hecha con asp.net y con servidor IIS me sale el siguiente error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).**

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Tu proyecto tiene una referencia (librería) del tipo COM que está fallando.....por casualidad no estarás usando interop o algo similar para crear el Word??

Comment: @Yussef sip uso el interop sabes donde puedo descargar el dll?

Comment: Ni idea de donde se descarga, prueba agregar la dll desde tu computador en el servidor, seguramente deberás registrar esa dll. Yo tuve el mismo problema hace muchísimo años con el interop, la única solución que me función fue instalar oficce en el servidor (no digo que no exista una solución menos bruta). De ahí en adelante no lo usé más

Comment: @Yussef instale el office 2016 plus en el servidor pero sigue igual :(

Comment: Puede ser un asunto de permisos, porque el servidor que supongo es IIS usa el usuario IIS_IUSRS y tu el office lo instalaste seguramente con otro usuario